# How to fix incorrect mime-type (atom-feed) showed in chrome-devtools?

Tags: php, nginx, google-chrome-devtools, mime-types, atom-feed

I'm not sure if the problem occurs because of wrong PHP-code or maybe a wrong configuration of nginx.

I like to generate a feed in atom-format. The XML of the feed is valid. I do set the content-type via

```
header("Content-type: application/atom+xml");
```

before I put out the XML. Nonetheless, I get different information from chromium developer-tools.
The tableview in *Network* shows me **text/plain** as type:

[image: table view looks bad]

However, the header itself seems okay as it states **application/atom+xml**:

[image: header details look okay]

This mime-type is correctly set inside nginx-configuration:

```
types {
        [...]
        application/atom+xml                    atom;
        [...]
}
```

What could be missing/wrong that chromium does not recognize the correct mime-type of my feed and states it as text/plain?

Comment: Consult a third party -- try `curl -i`. Is it possible that `text/plain` is just an artifact of Chromium's content handling?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be Chrome not regognizing the `application/*+xml` content type. It looks that you need to use plain old `application/xml` to get XSLT processing and correct Content-Type display to work in dev tools.

Comment: That seems both replicable and irritating, as I switched to providing the xml statically as pre-built file instead of generating it with php, and: the content type is today recognized correctly by chrome and was it by the time of writing, I'm quite sure.